# Right click only registers when i RELEASE (and not press) the button of the mouse

Tags: mouse, right-click

Not sure when this started (i think it was like 6 months ago when i upgraded to windows 10) but my right click mouse button only registers the click when i release the button and not when i click on it (how it should be).

I have tried to google this problem over and over again and it is getting particularly annoying since i play alot of games that need a normal right click to be played properly.

I'm pretty sure its not a mouse problem (using a steelseries sensei atm) because this mouse is working correctly on other pc`s and the problem persists when im using my touchpad buttons of my laptop. I hope i explained it correctly.

Comment: In what? I'm fairly sure my mouse has always had this behaviour in Windows, unless you mean it doesn't register at all... otherwise drag and drop would be quite hard/impossible.

Comment: No, left click action like drag and drop are working perfectly. The problem is the right click. For example (easy to explain this way), in games like counter strike, where you press right mouse button to aim when sniping, the sights only appear when i release the right click button making me a little slower to aim and thus less capable of playig correctly.

Comment: You can test if this is actually occurring globally by pressing and holding the right mouse button over an icon on the desktop. While you continue to hold, you should be able to bring a slightly transparent copy of the icon around the desktop. Upon release, the icon should move to the space on the desktop where your cursor was during release. If this works, then your clicking behavior is working as it is designed to by default. In that case, this sounds like game behavior that is typically set in the game's config. This site does not allow questions specifically pertaining to video games.

Comment: drag and drop is functioning correctly both on left and right click button. Its not a game config setup issue, as this problem started happening both on desktop and on several games. One cannot explain this problem properly if not talking about the ingame issues this brings wich is the most frustrating part.

Comment: If you are able to click and drag a desktop icon with the right mouse button as mentioned, the button is registering the correct action on press, prior to release.

Comment: ok, now i understand the confusion. On one hand its functioning the correct way, as its dragging and recognizing the click. But on another, this is what is happening sometimes; i press the right click button on the desktop (not selecting anything) and it opens the normal options menu upon the pressing itself, but on some other times the options menu only appears when i release the button. Another aspect i didnt mention is upon holding the right click button on some games it doesnt recognize the holding.

Comment: Have you tried another mouse? Another USB port? Do you have the correct drivers? If on a laptop, do you experience the same thing when pressing the laptop's right click button or after double tapping the touch pad?

Comment: ok, i have tried another mouse and as far as ingame goes, its working normally. Outside of games, on desktop, the option menu only appears when i release the button, i think this is actually normal. I guess the problem may be from my normal mouse? On my normal mouse (ingame) sometimes the intended right click action occurs when pressing the button and other times only occurs when i release it.. On top of that actions that require holding the right click button dont occur at all depending on how much pressure i aplly on the button. I guess ill try to go to the shop and replace it :/

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using the newest drivers for the original mouse?

Comment: yes i can confirm. I will try out this mouse on the same games but on another pc to get the final answer.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd-party scripting software such as a mouse macro to increase your gaming performance (for example, a rapid-click script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mouse is defective - be it the cable, USB connection, physical buttons, logic board, ect. The issue as you describe it does not occur when you change the mouse out with another.

Ensure that you are using the latest drivers for the problematic mouse and that there is no obvious physical damage (exposed cabling, loose connection at the mouse or USB level, ect).

If you're not sold, a great test for confirmation would be to try the mouse in another computer.